# UINavigationViewController - different right button on each subsequent VC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to build a fairly trivial phonebook app with the following trivial workflow: `FirstViewController` -> `SecondViewController` -> `ThirdViewController` etc.

My understanding is that `UINavigationController` is exactly the one to handle such workflow. So, I embedded the `FirstViewController` in `NavigationController` and added segues between controllers. So far so good.

My problem is with making the navigation bar on each of the controllers have a different right button (e.g. a detail view would have an "Edit" right button, an edit view would have a "Save" one, etc.) I am able to add the right button only on the `FirstViewController` (via Xcode) because this VC got Navigation Item (when it got embedded into the navigation controller). Subsequent VCs don't have such Navigation Item and even though they get the navigation bar with the "Back" button, I cannot find a way (in Xcode) to add a right button.

What would be the recommended way to add such right buttons for each subsequent view controllers (via Xcode or programmatically)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can customize NavigationBar content for every UIViewController directly from them. For this, you have to set those element from their `navigationItem` property.
From it you can set multiple elements, including but not limited to `rightBarButtonItems` and `leftBarButtonItems`.

Once the UIViewController is pushed onto a UINavigationController stack, those settings will be used to customize navigation bar appearance.

For more details, have a look at [UINavigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem) documentation

**Edit:** Here a good explanation about how to achieve what you want only from Storyboards https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/14/adding-buttons-to-the-navigation-bar-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Navigation Bar in each VC and inside add the item that you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work - whenever I drag Navigation Bar to the VC, it ends up as a child of the top View, which doesn't make sense. Is there anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky. First you have to add a Navigation Item to the second and third view controllers. It looks like this in the library:

[image]

Just drag that right onto the second view controller and then onto the third view controller.

*Now* you will be able to add a right bar button item to the second and third view controllers exactly as you did for the first view controller.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the original contents of the VC: https://s24.postimg.org/83kocwj9x/Screen_Shot_2017_01_16_at_12_11_32_AM.png . Now, when I drag Navigation Item to this VC, indeed, I get a Navigation Item named "Title" but it lacks the "Left Bar Button Items" and "Right Bar Button Items" sub-items and I cannot add any buttons to it: https://s24.postimg.org/700k0xymt/Screen_Shot_2017_01_16_at_12_13_20_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

Write this method in each view controller and call it from viewDidLoad

```
    func customizeRightBarButton() {

    let rightBarButtonImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "customImage")
    let rightBarButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    rightBarButton.setImage(rightBarButtonImage, forState: .Normal)
    rightBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23)
    let barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButton)
    rightBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```

If you wanna hide back bar button then use

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do that.

```
   let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "YourImage"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourClass.yourFunction(_:)))

   self.navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Add this code and all the view controllers you want to add a right button besides the back button.

I hope that this code help you!